# how to store custom attributes for token information in JSON and use for training

Tags: nlp, spacy

Using [gold.docs_to_json](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse#docs_to_json), I am unable to store custom token attributes in JSON

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "paragraphs": [
        {
            "raw": "Complete the nlp task",
            "sentences": [
                {
                    "tokens": [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "orth": "Complete",
                            "tag": "VB",
                            "head": 0,
                            "dep": "ROOT",
                            "ner": "O"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "orth": "the",
                            "tag": "DT",
                            "head": 2,
                            "dep": "det",
                            "ner": "O"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "orth": "nlp",
                            "tag": "NN",
                            "head": 1,
                            "dep": "compound",
                            "ner": "O"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "orth": "task",
                            "tag": "NN",
                            "head": -3,
                            "dep": "dobj",
                            "ner": "O"
                        }
                    ],
                    "brackets": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I store custom attributes as well?
Also can I train the custom attributes with `spacy train` as well.

---

**irrevelent details:**
I know that a custom doc_to_json can be made which will store the custom attributes as well but If I am unable to train the model to label custom attributes then it is of no use.

Comment: What component are you trying to train using the custom attributes?

Comment: @aab  For example: I have a custom attribute `token._.tasktype` and I would like to train this.